# How do I use Tkinter buttons to open webrowsers properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Everything looks right, but when I run the program the **buttons** and the **websites** open at the same time and then the **buttons** don't work?

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style()

open_facebook = webbrowser.open('http://www.facebook.com')
open_google = webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')
open_yahoo = webbrowser.open('http://www.yahoo.com')
open_youtube = webbrowser.open('http://www.youtube.com')

style.configure("TButton",
                font="Serif 18",
                padding=10)

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

button_facebook = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Facebook', command=open_facebook).grid(row=1, column=0)
button_google = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Google', command=open_google).grid(row=1, column=1)
button_yahoo = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Yahoo', command=open_yahoo).grid(row=1, column=2)
button_youtube = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Youtube', command=open_youtube).grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you do `open_facebook = webbrowser.open('http://www.facebook.com')` it opens the website then. Change them to: `open_facebook = lambda: webbrowser.open('http://www.facebook.com')` so they create functions that don't do it until called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't manage to make it work with the code you had presented, but I could  make it work using lambda in the command portion of the button. This was the only way I could ensure that the web browser didn't open the sites until the buttons were pressed.

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("TButton",
            font="Serif 18",
            padding=10)

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

button_facebook = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Facebook', command= lambda: 
webbrowser.open('http://www.facebook.com'))
button_google = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Google', command= lambda: 
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com'))
button_yahoo = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Yahoo', command= lambda: 
webbrowser.open('http://www.yahoo.com'))
button_youtube = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Youtube', command= lambda: 
webbrowser.open('http://www.youtube.com'))

button_facebook.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_google.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_yahoo.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_youtube.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Y'all rock Thank you!